# Where is the location of the template files of pinax-stripe package?

Tags: python, django, pinax

I have installed the following package in my django application:

Pinax Stripe : https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe

In my application, I can see the page for 'add subscription' after I add this application to my settings.py file. I have attached a screenshot:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Y3I.png)

But when I browse its files, I can only see email templates but I can't see any templates for the web pages. Can anyone point me in the right direction where they are?

Comment: Looks like this has been a problem for others in past as well. Checkout this github Issue on the repo: [link](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-stripe/issues/243)

Have you looked for a pinax-bootstrap-theme folder in your project? My  guess is that this second package was installed with the original pinax-stripe download. Your templates likely live in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found what appears to be the correct template files on [Github](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-theme-bootstrap/tree/master/pinax_theme_bootstrap/templates/pinax/stripe). The easiest way to setup the template would just to be to install the entire package.

First, install pinax-theme-bootstrap using:

```
pip install pinax-theme-bootstrap
```

Then, following their instructions online:

> Include pinax-theme-bootstrap in your requirements file and include pinax_theme_bootstrap and bootstrapform (which is installed alongside this theme) in your INSTALLED APPS.
>
> Add django.core.context_processors.request and pinax_theme_bootstrap.context_processors.theme to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS to ensure the user selector and site name work correctly.
>
> Make sure both template loaders and staticfiles finders includes app directories.
>
> Site name comes from Sites fixture.
>
> Your site_base.html should extend theme_bootstrap/base.html and should provide footer and nav blocks (the latter should just be a ul of li of a links).
>
> Your pages should have blocks head_title and body and should extend site_base.html.
>
> The url name home should be defined as the homepage.