# Stripe: When customer adds card I'm able to receive and store 'source' token in customer model. But Not able to charge customer

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, stripe-payments

**ERROR:**

CardError at /book-now/ Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

---

```
def book_now(request):
"""Schedule Appointment"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
    token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')

    customer.default_source = token
    customer.save()

    charges.create(
        amount=decimal.Decimal("119.99"),
        customer=request.user.customer.stripe_id,
    )

return render(request, 'appointment/book_now.html')
```

Here you can see that I save the token to a Customer. This works successfully. Then When I try to charge customer I get the error that they do not have a card.

When I log in to stripe.com, the user does not have a card. And I understand this part because token was never sent to stripe. But my thinking is that it would be sent during the charge.

**Note:** Upon user registration a customer object for that user is created.

Comment: May I ask what language library you're using?  That's not the official `stripe-python` library, from what I can tell.  It's tough to say what could be going wrong because you're proxying the requests through this method somehow.  I think your best bet is honestly just to get a log for one of your failing requests and inspect the customer record associated with it.  That'll almost definitely point you at what's going wrong.

Comment: @korben pinax-stripe its a django app. (python)

Comment: pinax-stripe workflow is 1.User add a card. 2.User pay with related card

Comment: @Denis havent been able to find any of the details on that in the documentation. Would you mind pointing me in the right direction? Anyways I have got it working using this:

Comment: token = request.POST.get('stripeToken')..........
  customer = stripe.Customer.retrieve(request.user.customer.stripe_id)..........
  customer.sources.create(source=token)

Comment: @questnofinterest did you sync everything? https://pinax-stripe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started/

Comment: @Denis None of the urls are working such as 'payments/payment-methods/create

Comment: @questnofinterest did you include them in project?

Comment: @Denis yes I added "path('payments/', include('pinax.stripe.urls')),"... but i it doesnt seem that any html files for the templates are in the pinax-stripe site-packages folder. I then found this stackoverflow answer... What do you think? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38021293/8854130

Comment: @questnofinterest I think what they have unclear and outdated docs. I stuck with that stuff 1-2 days before also. Yes, you need install pinax because only root project has template folder.

Comment: @Denis wow I cannot get this to work lol. Did you user something instead of pinax?

Comment: @questnofinterest No, I figure out how to use pinax